# Does releasing a UIView automatically calls removeFromSuperView?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I saw that this question has been asked the other way around, well my question is if I release a UIView that has a superview, does calling the [myView release] will subsequently clean up by calling [removeFromSuperview]? I'm guessing that it does, because I don't see any leaks, but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not.

You probably don't have leaks because a leak means an unreferenced pointer, and the view will still be referenced by its parent. (And when the parent is released, it will get rid of children.)

Comment: I made a little test, and you are right, releasing won't remove them from the superview. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call removeFromSuperview unless you need that view to be removed from it's superview while the user is still looking at it. In other words, use it as a presentational tool and not a memory management one unless you are queueing lots of images in a scroll view or something of that nature. Beyond that, superviews manage their subviews when they're released.

Also, if you remain in a view controller and you remove a view that's been retained, that doesn't release it. Nor does releasing a view in a still active view controller remove it from the superview (unless you've subclassed it to do so).

Answer (score 1):

In the UIView class reference documentation

```
 addSubview:

 Adds a view to the end of the receiver’s list of subviews.
 (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view Parameters

 view

 The view to be added. **This view is retained by the receiver**. After being added, this view appears on top of any other subviews.
```

Releasing the UIView only affects the reference count. If the reference count is zero, it is deallocated. Otherwise, it is assumed to be held by others until they all release it.